# Pandas - normalize Json list

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I am trying to normalize a column from a Pandas dataframe that is a list of dictionaries (can be missing).

**Example to reproduce**

```
import pandas as pd
bids = pd.Series([[{'price': 606, 'quantity': 28},{'price': 588, 'quantity': 29},
                   {'price': 513, 'quantity': 33}],[],[{'price': 7143, 'quantity': 15},
                    {'price': 68, 'quantity': 91},{'price': 6849, 'quantity': 12}]])
data = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).rename(columns={0:'id'})
data['bids'] = bids
```

**Desired output**

```
id price quantity
1  606    28
1  588    29
1  513    33
3  7143   15
3  68     91
3  6849   12
```

**Attempt**

Trying to resolve using pandas json_normalize, following docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). I'm confused by why none of the below work, and what type of record_path will fix my problem. All the below error.

```
pd.json_normalize(data['bids'])
pd.json_normalize(data['bids'],['price','quantity'])
pd.json_normalize(data['bids'],[['price','quantity']])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding another approach with `np.repeat` and `np.concatenate` with `json_normalize`

```
out = pd.io.json.json_normalize(np.concatenate(data['bids']))
out.insert(0,'id',np.repeat(data['id'],data['bids'].str.len()).to_numpy())
```

Or you can also use `np.hstack` as @Shubham mentions instead of `np.concatenate`:

```
out = pd.io.json.json_normalize(np.hstack(data['bids']))
```

---

```
print(out)

   id  price  quantity
0   1    606        28
1   1    588        29
2   1    513        33
3   3   7143        15
4   3     68        91
5   3   6849        12
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on column `bids` then create a new dataframe from the dictionaries in exploded `bids` column and use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to `join` it with `df`:

```
df = data.explode('bids').dropna(subset=['bids']).reset_index(drop=True)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df.pop('bids').tolist()))
```

Result:

```
print(df)
   id  price  quantity
0   1    606        28
1   1    588        29
2   1    513        33
3   3   7143        15
4   3     68        91
5   3   6849        12
```